# Replace strings that do not contain certain punctuation in R

Tags: r, regex

I aim to replace strings that do not contain a certain punctuation: '/'.

```
sentence = 'I/NP to/INF this/NP like/CON that/NP Peter wow er ! is'
```

[Peter, wow, !, er, is] these elements are not stuck with '/', so it is necessary to tag them with '/UN'.

This is what I've tried for this

```
    seg = unlist(strsplit(sentence, '[[:space:]]+'))
    segment = seg[!grepl('\\/',seg)]
    replace = gsub('(\\S+)','\\1/UN',segment)

    library(stringr)
    mgsub <- function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
      if (length(pattern)!=length(replacement)) {
        stop("pattern and replacement do not have the same length.")
      }
      result <- x
      for (i in 1:length(pattern)) {
        result <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], result, ...)
      }
      result
    }

    mgsub(segment, replace, sentence)
```

However, unfortunately, what I got is this result below.

```
[1] "I/NP to/INF this/UN/NP like/CON that/NP Peter/UN/UN wow/UN er/UN !/UN is/UN"
```

This is what I aim to achieve:

```
[1] "I/NP to/INF this/NP like/CON that/NP Peter/UN wow/UN er/UN !/UN is/UN"
```

Please do not be stuck with the sample - `sentence` but consider more possible examples so THE code may get through all of them.

Comment: Just out of curiosity how are you generating the POS tags? I would presume that eg OpenNLP are tagging your leftovers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add `/UN` to all words that do not contain `/`, you could use gsub. For example

```
gsub("(?<=^| )([^\\/ ]+)(?= |$)","\\1\\2/UN\\3", sentence, perl=T)
# [1] "I/NP to/INF this/NP like/CON that/NP Peter/UN wow/UN er/UN !/UN is/UN"
```

This regular expression looks for a string of letters that don't contain an slash or space `([^\\/ ]+)` sandwiched between a spaces or the boundary of the string.

Comment: Thank you! It is brilliant!